# Converting a cross product typically found in electrodynamics between coordinate systems

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

**Context**

There are numerous posts on mathstackexchange and physicsstack exchange that seek clarity regarding conversion from a Cartesian coordinate system to curvilinear coordinate system, or viceversa [1,2]. Yet, none of them seem complete to me. So, I want to ask a  question here that I think illuminates the matter. One of the thorny issues for me is that a coordinates triple might be given in spherical coordinates (or cylindrical coordinates), but the basis vectors appear to to Cartesian. For example the distance, $d$ between $P$ given by $\mathbf{r}$ and $Q$ given by $\mathbf{r}'$ is
\begin{align}
d &= \left\|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'\right\| 
\\
d &= \left\|
\left(x- x'\right)\,\hat{\mathbf{x}}  
+
\left(y- y'\right)\,\hat{\mathbf{y}} 
+
\left(z- z'\right)\,\hat{\mathbf{z}} 
\right\| 
\\
&= \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \vdots
\\
&=
\sqrt{\left(x- x'\right)^2+ \left(y- y'\right)^2+ \left(z- z'\right)^2 } 
\end{align}
This computation is done in Cartesian coordiantes with Cartesian basis vectors. Often, I see  [3]
\begin{align}
d &= \left\|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'\right\| 
\\
d &= \left\|
\left(r\,\sin\theta\,\cos\varphi- r'\,\sin\theta'\,\cos\varphi'\right)\,\hat{\mathbf{x}}  
+
\left(r\,\sin\theta\,\sin\varphi- r'\,\sin\theta'\,\sin\varphi'\right)\,\hat{\mathbf{y}}  
+
\left(r\,\cos\theta- r'\,\cos\theta'\right)\,\hat{\mathbf{z}}  
\right\| 
\\
&= \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \vdots
\\
&=
\sqrt{r^2+r'^2-2rr'(\sin{\theta}\sin{\theta'}\cos{(\varphi-\varphi')} + \cos{\theta}\cos{\theta'})}
\end{align}
Notice that the basis vectors were always Cartesian, even though the coordinates were spherical.

**Question**

In electrodynamics, the practitioner is often concerned with integrals with two sets of coordinates. For example, with an integral  similar to
$$
X(\mathbf{r}) = \int_{V} f(\mathbf{r}') \times   (\mathbf{r}-  \mathbf{r}')\, dV'.
$$
Here, I use a cross product $\times$ but similar forms exist with dot products or standard products.  Let, say that the function $f$ has very clear spherical symmetry, how can we write
$$f(\mathbf{r}^\prime )\times 
\left( \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}^\prime\right)$$
in the spherical system. Please, rather than give a triple in parenthesis, please explicitly include basis vectors in your answer.

Let, say that the function $g$ has very clear cylindrical symmetry, how can we write
$$g(\mathbf{r}^\prime )\times 
\left( \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}^\prime\right)$$
in the cylindrical system. Please, rather than give a triple in parenthesis, please explicitly include basis vectors in your answer.

**Bibliography**

[1]
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/529113/how-do-the-unit-vectors-in-spherical-coordinates-combine-to-result-in-a-generic

[2]
[Vector sum in spherical coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17517/vector-sum-in-spherical-coordinates/17521#17521)

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Answer (score 1):

The cylindrical unit vectors are related to the Cartesian unit vectors by
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}\\\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\\\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\phi&\sin\phi&0\\-\sin\phi&\cos\phi&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}\\\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}\\\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}\end{bmatrix}
$$
[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates). The components of a vector
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{u}&=u^x\,\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}+u^y\,\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}+u^z\,\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}
=u^\rho\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}+u^\phi\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}+u^z\,\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}
\end{align}
are related as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}u^\rho\\u^\phi\\u^z\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\phi&\sin\phi&0\\-\sin\phi&\cos\phi&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}u^x\\u^y\\u^z\end{bmatrix}\,.
$$
Using
$$
\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}=\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}\,,\quad\quad \hat{\boldsymbol{x}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}=-\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}=-\sin\phi\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}-\cos\phi\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\,,\quad\quad\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}=\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}=\cos\phi\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}-\sin\phi\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\,
$$
we get
$$\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Big|}
\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}=\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}\,,\quad
\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}=-\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\,,\quad
\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}=\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}\,.\quad}
$$
Proof:

> \begin{align}\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}&=\cos\phi^2\,(\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{y}})+\sin^2\phi\,(\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{y}})\,,\\\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}&=\cos\phi\,(\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{z}})+\sin\phi\,(\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{z}})=-(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi)\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\,,\\\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}&=-\sin\phi\,(\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{z}})+\cos\phi\,(\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}\times\hat{\boldsymbol{z}})=(\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi)\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}\,.\end{align}

The cross product of the two vectors
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{u}&=u^\rho\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}+u^\phi\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}+u^z\,\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}&\boldsymbol{v}&=v^\rho\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}+v^\phi\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}+v^z\,\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}\\
\end{align}
in cylindrical coordinates is therefore formally equal to the cross product in Cartesian coordinates:
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{u}\times\boldsymbol{v}
=(u^\phi v^z-u^zv^\phi)\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}+(u^zv^\rho-u^\rho v^z)\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}+(u^\rho v^\phi-u^\phi v^\rho)\,\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}\,.
\end{align}

Use the same approach for spherical coordinates. The transformation matrix is given in the same link  [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates).

Comment: Kurt, This is nicely put together. The notation is great. However, in my opinion, the question is not answered. We have $f(\mathbf{r}) \times\left( \mathbf{r} -\mathbf{r}^\prime  \right)$

Comment: The formulas I derived will enable you to write down the cross product of *any* two vectors in spherical coordinates. In particular, $f(\mathbf{r}) \times\left( \mathbf{r} -\mathbf{r}^\prime  \right)\,.$ You might learn something from proceeding with that exercise. Another reason I choose this generic format was that there was once a controversy about the boxed formulas [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1476392/949989).